# Count filtered records in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

As I am new to scala ,This problem might look very basic to all..
I have a file called data.txt which contains like below:

```
xxx.lss.yyy23.com-->mailuogwprd23.lss.com,Hub,12689,14.98904563,1549
xxx.lss.yyy33.com-->mailusrhubprd33.lss.com,Outbound,72996,1.673717588,1949
xxx.lss.yyy33.com-->mailuogwprd33.lss.com,Hub,12133,14.9381027,664
xxx.lss.yyy53.com-->mailusrhubprd53.lss.com,Outbound,72996,1.673717588,3071
```

I want to split the line and find the records depending upon the numbers   in xxx.lss.yyy23.com

```
 val data = io.Source.fromFile("data.txt").getLines().map { x => (x.split("-->"))}.map { r => r(0) }.mkString("\n")
```

which gives me

```
xxx.lss.yyy23.com
xxx.lss.yyy33.com
xxx.lss.yyy33.com
xxx.lss.yyy53.com
```

This is what I am trying to count the exact value...

```
 data.count { x => x.contains("33")}
```

How do I get the count of records who does not contain 33...

Comment: I think you want `length` instead of `count`, and it has to be called on the list not on the println.

Comment: @pedrofurla  No..length will give the count of character of the string..

Comment: Check what `getLines()` returns.

Comment: you also can replace `filter` for `count` to get the same result. Either way, I assure you `println(...).count` makes no sense.

Comment: Yaa...I have updated the question..

Comment: Ah! Sorry, now I noticed a `.mkString("\n")` at the end of `data` assignment. Remove that and you'll get you answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will give you the number of lines that contain "33":

```
data.split("\n").count(a => a.contains("33"))
```

The reason what you have above isn't working is that you need to split `data` into an array of strings again.  Your previous statement actually concatenates the result into a single string using newline as a separator using `mkstring`, so you can't really run collection operations like count on it.

The following will work for getting the lines that do not contain "33":

```
data.split("\n").count(a => !a.contains("33"))
```

You simply need to negate the contains operation in this case.